# Out to exit debug mode with orange boxes

Tags: firefox-os

I've a Firefox OS 1.3 on ZTE Open C device. By mistake, I selected the wrong debug option and now I can't use my phone normally: I have an orange box (surrounding elements) that I can move only by sliding to the right the center of the screen.

Do someone know how I can get to the configuration panel and remove this?
I rebooted the phone, even removed the battery, but the option is still here.

---

I figured out that this is the **Screen Reader** mode. And there are instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Debugging/Developer_settings#Show_screen_reader_settings).
But in my 1.3 version, the up-down-up-down-up-down doesn't work. Neither the swipe with two fingers...

Comment: @Tolokban feel free to contact the developers at dev-fxos@lists.mozilla.org

Comment: @Tolokban the easy fix is to factory reset the phone.